# Using JavaScript's library chosen.js, how can I change the value of a specific option?

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Before I had chosen.js I could find the specific option, remove it, and then create a new option instead, giving it the same value as it the deleted option has...

Now it doesn't work... the select itself changes - but it is hidden when using chosen.js...

And what was supposed to be a simple task is not simple at all!

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$("#your_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` after updating select options.

Just as is written in reference: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events